# Switching attribute code for two attributes

Tags: attributes, eav

we have two attributes for color. A multiple select *color* (for all used colors on a shirt) and a select color *main_color* for Google shopping.

Now we have some shopping extensions that default to the *color* attribute. And break because this is a multiple select instead of single value. Now we could just change that. The problem is that these attributes have been populated for *all* our products.

**Question:** is there an easy way to switch the attribute code for these two attributes - whilst keeping the values linked?

Answer (score 0):

The only place where the attribute code is kept is the `eav_attribute` table (I think).
So you can switch the `attribute_code` value for the 2 attributes.
Clear the cache and rebuild your indexes.

But back-up your db in case I'm wrong.

Of course you could get strange results if you have code sections that call specifically `$_product->getColor()` or `getMainColor()`.

Comment: will try (and test via backup). thx